# How to check if a result of find is inside a link

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
      <a href=""><div class="subdiv"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to unrwap the main div for the `.subdiv`. I do it in this way:

```
$('#content').find('.subdiv').unwrap();
```

Now I have the problem that sometime the `.subdiv` div in inside a link.

How I can check if `.subdiv` is inside a link and switch the `unwrap` to the link?

I tried it like this, but it failed:

```
if( $('#content').find('.subdiv a').length>0)
{
    $('#content').find('.subdiv a').unwrap();
}
else
{
    $('#content').find('.subdiv').unwrap();
}
```

Comment: What is the resulting structure you want? Rory and I seem to read the question differently, and Rory's a bright guy, so that makes me worry I'm misreading it...

Comment: Yeah I think there's definitely some confusion here - mostly mine :) @mikeD could you please edit the question to show an example of the HTML output you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can check if `.subdiv` is inside a link and switch the `unwrap` to the link?

Using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), which finds the closest ancestor element matching a selector (starting with the element itself and working up toward the document element):

```
var el = $("#content").find(".subdiv");
var a = el.closest("a");
if (a.length) {
    el = a;
}
el.unwrap();
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log("Note that 'sub' is red and bold");
setTimeout(function() {
    var el = $("#content").find(".subdiv");
    var a = el.closest("a");
    if (a.length) {
        el = a;
    }
    el.unwrap();
    console.log("Unwrapped, it's no longer red and bold");
}, 800);
```

```css
#main a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
      <a href=""><div class="subdiv">sub</div></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot and thanks for your notice, in my real code i work with classes, thats the reason i do it this way $("#content").find(".subdiv") ;-))

Answer (score 0):

`unwrap()` only works on parent elements. As the HTML structure can change in your case you would probably be better off just selecting the `.subdiv` element directly, then appending it to the required location, like this:

```js
$('#content .subdiv').appendTo('#content');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  #content
  <div id="main">
    #main
    <a href="#">
      Link
      <div class="subdiv">#subdiv</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this wont help me, i have the html structure as it is and i have at start point the subdiv wich i have to unwrap (but take care for a possible link)

Comment: Apologies - I meant to append to `#content` as that's the original parent element when there is no `a` wrapping the `#subdiv`. However it would save any confusion if you could update the question to include an example of what you're expecting the HTML to look like after the unwrapping has been done.